# Input only 3 characters and 3 asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to program my code to only let users input 3 asterisk or 3 alphabets. The 2 different characters can't be used together. How can I do that?

For instance, user can input *** or AAA

I looked up some stuff on here and all I got was `regEx = \d{3}[a-zA-Z]{3}$/;`

This did not work for me.

Comment: The regex will simply be ***|[A-Za-z]{3} if you want exactly 3 asterisks or 3 letters.

Comment: If there are only two options, then why not use radio buttons?

Comment: Michael_B the input can be any combination of alphabets but as for asterisk user can only input 3 asterisks.

Comment: Maybe you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/apm5gU/1) `^(?:\*{3}|[A-Za-z]{3})$`

Comment: The fourth bird Thank you! It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/apm5gU/1):

`^(?:\*{3}|[A-Za-z]{3})$`

Between the beginning of the string `^` and the end of the string`$`, you can specify 3 times an * `\*{3}` or `|` 3 times `[A-Za-z]{3}`.

`(?:` is a [non capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).